# ¿Por qué se usa en español "matar" en vez de un derivado de otro verbo más común en latín?

Tags: etimología, verbos, historia, latín

Me da por investigar un poco sobre el origen de *matar* en español, y leo, [según el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/matar), que proviene del latín *mactāre* 'inmolar', 'sacrificar'. El caso es que me preguntaba si ese sería realmente el verbo que se usaba en latín como "matar", y en el sitio de latín me encuentro con [esta respuesta](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/768/2646), que incluye una extensa lista de verbos con dicho significado... y que no incluye *mactāre*.

El caso es que [he preguntado](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/14278/2646) si es que este verbo no era muy común o si se usaba mayormente con otro significado (como el de "ofrecer a los dioses" algo sin implicar un sacrificio) y por tanto no merece entrar en la lista de verbos de "matar". Lo malo es que a fecha de hoy la pregunta aún no ha sido respondida.

Así pues, doble pregunta:

- ¿Cómo es que el español acabó usando un verbo para "matar" que en latín podía ser poco usado o incluso usado con un significado diferente, más como "sacrificar"?
- ¿Existe en español algún sinónimo de "matar" que provenga de alguno de los otros verbos de la lista? ¿O incluso algún verbo o sustantivo derivados con significados relacionados? Los expongo a continuación: *interficere, perimere* (estos dos parece que eran los más comunes), *interimere, necare, occidere, jugulare, trucidare, obtruncare, percutere*. El italiano por ejemplo se decantó por un derivado de *occidere*.

Comment: Es interesante que en las lenguas iberoromances se hayan ido por la palabra *matar* a diferencia de otras lenguas romances (los derivados de occidere en rumano e italiano, o el tuer francés). Habría que buscar desde las muestras iniciales de estas lenguas.

Answer (score 6):

A su segunda pregunta, a bote pronto, recuerdo:

[**Occiso**](https://dle.rae.es/occiso):

> Del lat. *occīsus*, part. pas. de *occidĕre* 'matar'.
>
> 1. adj. Muerto violentamente. U. m. c. s.

[**Yugular<sup>2</sup>**](https://dle.rae.es/yugular):

> Del lat. *iugulāre*.
>
> 1. tr. Degollar, cortar el cuello.

[**Trucidar**](https://dle.rae.es/trucidar):

> Del lat. *trucidāre*.
>
> 1. tr. desus. Despedazar, matar con crueldad e inhumanidad.

[**Interfecto**](https://dle.rae.es/interfecto):

> Del lat. *interfectus*, part. pas. de *interficio* 'matar'.
>
> 1. adj. Der. Dicho de una persona: Muerta violentamente, en especial si ha sido víctima de una acción delictiva. U. m. c. s.

Y todas las palabras relacionadas con matar y muerte que, como suicidio, homicidio, parricidio, uxoricidio, genocidio, infanticidio, etc. terminan en [**-cidio**](https://dle.rae.es/-cidio)

> Del lat. *-cidium*, de la raíz de *caedĕre* 'matar'.
>
> 1. elem. compos. Significa 'acción de matar'. *Filicidio, suicidio*

o en [**-cida**](https://dle.rae.es/-cida?):

> Del lat. *-cīda*, de la raíz de *caedĕre* 'matar'.
>
> 1. elem. compos. Significa 'matador' o 'exterminador'. *Herbicida, insecticida.*

En cuanto a la etimología de "matar", y aunque las distintas ediciones del DLE, incluyendo la actual, indican su procedencia de *mactāre*, la edición de  1992 se desmarca e indica **etimología discutida**. Corominas descarta radicalmente la etimología *mactāre* (énfasis mio):

> Otras  etimologías  propuestas  pueden  eliminarse sin  escrúpulos.  **MACTARE**  'sacrificar'  palabra  no trasmitida  al  romance,  **es  absolutamente  imposible** desde  el  punto  de  vista  fonético  (aunque  todavía transijan  con  él  Bourciez,  Élem.  de  Ling.  Rom., §  183,  y  Entwistle,  Sp.  Lang.,  p.  68).

Comment: En el _Vocabulario Eclesiástico_ de 1499 ya se tenía "matar" como derivado de "mactare" 'matar, sacrificar'. Y añade que la versión sin 'c' se usaba en el ajedrez para dar el mate. Y en el _Fuero de Valfermoso de las Monjas_ de 1189 se lee "Qui mactaret perro qui lobos matat aut carnem escodire ad lupu pectet de decem menkales aiuso quantum iuraret su domno que ualebat", que indica que "mactare" se usaba en el latín del siglo XII con un significado similar al actual "matar".

Answer (score 0):

The origin of 'matar' and reasons for its adoption are difficult or impossible to determine, because a complete or accurate picture of the Latin spoken is Spain isn't available to us. Written records and documents were of necessity produced by the small educated class, and reflected their use of standard or "classical" Latin, or an approximation of it, in written materials, primarily for official, theological or educational purposes. Alongside this, various "registers" of everyday, common or "vulgar" Latin were spoken by the masses, unwritten and variable by region, over time, and according to situation. Much is known about this common language which evolved into spoken Spanish, but from mostly indirect sources, and a complete picture is, as Penny, A History of the Spanish Language, remarks, "inevitably incomplete."  The likely candidates for a verb meaning to 'kill' suggested in the answer to the second question were certainly used in the "classical" register, and may have been in the "vulgar" as well, possibly along with others that are less known or obscure, and possibly with meanings significantly divergent from their use in official Latin. The origin of 'matar' may be similarly obscure.

Answer (score 0):

Evolución de la lengua. Muchas palabras distan en su uso actual respecto del original. Matar ya estaba como tal en la primera edición del *Diccionario de Autoridades* (1734) y en el de Covarrubias (1611).